# Integral f(x) in the power series

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate the definite integral $$\int_0^{0.4}cos((\frac{5x}{2})^2)dx$$ with an accuracy of 0.0001 by expanding the integrand f(x) in a power series and integrating it term by term.

Admittedly, I slept over every math lecture I had, but I knew a little bit about integrals, so my first thought was to approach it as every integral I saw before:

$$\int_{0}^{0.4}cos((\frac{5x}{2})^2)dx=\int cos((\frac{5x}{2})^2)dx=\int\frac{2cos(t)^2}{5}dt=\frac{2}{5}\int cos(2t)^2dt=\frac{2}{5}\int\frac{1+cos(2t)}{2}dt=\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{2}\int 1+cos(2t)dt=\frac{1}{5}(\int1dt\int cos(2t)dt=\frac{1}{5}(t+\frac{sin(2t}{2})=\frac{1}{5}(\frac{5x}{2}+\frac{sin(2*\frac{5x}{2})}{2})=\frac{5x+sin(5x)}{10}|_{0}^{0.4}=\frac{5*0.4+sin(5*0.4)}{10}-\frac{5*0+sin(5*0}{10}=\frac{2sin(2)}{10}=0.2909$$

But my friend returned with 0.4762 and doesn't want to reveal what he has done. Teacher said that both answers and methods are wrong, can you help us out?

Edit: as far as I search there appears to be no similar tasks. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I will try to rewrite it, it's really hard to learn it, or I just suck :)

Comment: You may use [detextify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to learn some syntax.

Comment: I'm done! Took forever... If there's still issues, let me know.

Comment: $\cos(y^2)$ is not $\cos^2(y)$

Answer (score 2):

Use the taylor expansion of $\cos x$ to the nth term for which the error of the taylor polinomial is less than your tolerancy. Do the variable change $x=\frac{25t^2}{4}$ and now integrate the finite polynomial